# Ruby on Rails: 'rails generate plugin' error on rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rspec-rails

I've been self-learning developing rails plugin.
One referenced tutorial I'm using is [here](http://craig-russell.co.uk/2011/11/09/how-to-create-and-test-a-ruby-on-rails-plugin.html#.UGbQAJjA-M4).

Unfortunately, it seemed I got stuck since the first step when I run "rails generate plugin. It's returning an error saying "rspec [not found]".

```
c:\rails\test\rails generate plugin HelloWorld

    create  vendor/plugins/hello_world
    create  vendor/plugins/hello_world/MIT-LICENSE
    create  vendor/plugins/hello_world/README
    create  vendor/plugins/hello_world/Rakefile
    create  vendor/plugins/hello_world/init.rb
    create  vendor/plugins/hello_world/install.rb
    create  vendor/plugins/hello_world/uninstall.rb
    create  vendor/plugins/hello_world/lib
    create  vendor/plugins/hello_world/lib/hello_world.rb
     error  rspec [not found]
```

I tried to look for possible solutions myself. One that I tried was making an update of the project's bundler gem in hope that might come from a bug of plugin compatibility.
anyway, just in case it would help give you guys some clue on where it could go wrong, I also post my GemFile as follows.

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.1.1'
    gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0"
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
    gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
    gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'pg', '0.14.0'
    gem  'bundler', '1.2.0.rc.2'
    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    group :development do
      gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'

    end

    group :test do
      gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
      gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
      gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
    end
```

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's trying to generate template rspec examples for the plugin, but the rspec directory isn't there.  Did you run the rspec installer (`rails g rspec:install`) after adding rspec to your Gemfile?

Comment: I did run that already, but everything doesn't seem to work the same. I tested further with my experimental development. I can get my tested plugin class to load up. meaning that the rspec error has nothing to do with the function of the plugin class itself. but only problem is the rspec error is just still there.